# Prove $IM=N$ (Ideal multiplied with modules equal submodules)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring, $M$ is $R$-module, and $N$ is submodule of $M$.
Then $M$ is called a multiplication module if for each submodule $N$ of $M$ there exists an ideal $I$ of $R$ such that $N = IM$.

Let $$I=\{r\in R\vert rM\subseteq N\}.$$ (I have proved $I$ is ideal of $R$)

> **In this case it is easy to prove that $$IM = N.$$**

To prove that, I will proof $IM\subseteq N$ and $N\subseteq IM$.

Let $a\in IM$, then $a=rm$, for $r\in R$ such that $rM\subseteq N$ and $m\in M$.

So, we have
$$a=rm\in rM\subseteq N.$$
Hence, $a\in N$. So, $IM\subseteq N$.

(1) Is this proof true?

Now I confused to proof $N\subseteq IM$. Let $n\in N$, I don't know how to get $n\in IM$.

(2) Is there any hint to proof this part?

Comment: What makes you think $IM = N$, or what conditions did you miss ? Try with $R=\Bbb{Z},M = \Bbb{Z}^2,N=\Bbb{Z}\times 2\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: I forget to add the definition of multiplication module. Please see my edited question.

Comment: Hint for (2): $IM\subseteq N$, hence there exists an ideal $J$ such that $JIM=N$.